# Perl shuffle letters

Tags: perl

Done below I have string, that it being split by each character. I want to split each words that has 4 or more letters. Basically $string[0] and [-1] remains untouched, other elements in between is supposed to be shuffled randomly.
And then joined with element 0 and -1. This is incredibly difficult for me.
Any ideas?

My desired output would be something like this (different each time obviosuly):
I hvae cnotrucetd a srtnig taht ndees to be suffelhd

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
        use List::Util qw(shuffle);

        my $string= "I have constructed a string that needs to be shuffled";

        my @characters = split(//,$string);
        foreach (@characters) {
        print($_, "\n");
        }

@characters = shuffle($character[1](@characters[1..$characters-1]));
```

Comment: Is this a homework question? It's okay, we will answer homework questions. But hopefully, if we know, the answer will be geared more towards helping you to learn rather than getting you out of a hole

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(shuffle);

my $string= "I have constructed a string that needs to be shuffled";

my @characters = split(//,$string);

foreach (@characters) {
    print($_, "\n");
}

my @shuffled;

# assign the first and last elements to the shuffled array
$shuffled[0] = $characters[0];
$shuffled[$#characters] = $characters[$#characters];

@shuffled[1 .. $#characters - 1]  = shuffle(@characters[1 .. $#characters - 1]);

foreach (@shuffled) {
    print($_, "\n");
}
```

Issues:

1. Use strict, use warnings. Your code refers to a @character array you didn't define: `$character[1]`
2. $#array gives the last index (not the length!) of @array. You use the array in scalar context ($array) which gives the length where you wanted the last index.
3. Corrected your list slice syntax

Comment: Again thank you, but. The first and last letter in each word should not change, and if the words are less than 4 characters, they are to be ignored. Hope I make myself clear. Cheers tho!

Comment: Then split the words apart with a split on whitespace then shuffle each using the above.

Comment: I'm having difficulties understandig you, I'm eager to learn, perhaps its just a noob vs pro, or a language barrier. How would I split each?

Comment: Split on `/\s+/` which will give a list of word strings then sort each word.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you want, you have a string like this:

```
 I have constructed a string that needs to be shuffled
```

and you want to shuffle all of the words. However, if a word is a small word, you want to combine it with a longer word. For example, you want to divide the string like this:

```
 I | have | constructed | a string | that | needs | to be | shuffled
```

You want the first and last word to remain in place:

```
 I ??? shuffled
```

And you want all the others shuffled:

```
 I constructed have needs that a string to be | shuffled
```

I like to take things one at a time:

1. Divide the string into separate words.
2. Create an array of all the words you want to shuffle.
3. Go through that array of words, and if a word is less than the minimum amount, append the following word.
4. Shuffle that array you created in Step #3
5. Print your sentence

Here's the program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use List::Util qw(shuffle);

use constant {
    MIN_WORD_LENGTH => 4,
    SENTENCE        => "I have constructed a string that needs to be shuffled",
};


#
# Split the sentence into words
#
my @sentence = split /\s+/, SENTENCE;

#
# @words are the words to be shuffled
#
my @words = @sentence[1..$#sentence - 1];

my @combined_words;     #Same as @words but smaller words are combined
my $word_to_push;
for my $word (@words) {
    #
    # Combine short words with the next one
    #
    if ( not defined $word_to_push ) {
        $word_to_push = $word;
    }
    else {
        $word_to_push .= " " . $word;
    }
    #
    # If the word_to_push is long enough, push it
    #
    if ( length $word_to_push >= MIN_WORD_LENGTH ) {
        push @combined_words, $word_to_push;
        undef $word_to_push;
    }
}

#
# Now shuffle the words
my @shuffle_words  = shuffle @combined_words;
say "$sentence[0] @shuffle_words $sentence[-1]";
```

And the results are (running three times):

```
I that a string have constructed needs to be shuffled
I to be that a string needs constructed have shuffled
I that to be a string constructed have needs shuffled
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for. I can't think what commentary I should provide, so please ask questions if you need to

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw(shuffle);

my $string= "I have constructed a string that needs to be shuffled";
my @ch = split //, $string;
my $shuffled = join '', $ch[0], shuffle(@ch[1..$#ch-1]), $ch[-1];

print $shuffled, "\n";
```

**example output**

```
Isedr  hricfes  enandts afltashnou t gothetucte evb d
```

---

**Update**

I think I understand you better, although you haven't confirmed. This may do what you ask. But is this a homework question?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw/ shuffle /;

my $string= "I have constructed a string that needs to be shuffled";

my @string = map {
  /\S/ && length($_) > 4 ? shuffle_word($_) : $_
} split /(\s+)/, $string;

print join('', @string), "\n";


sub shuffle_word {
  my ($word) = @_;
  my @word = split //, $word;
  join '', $word[0], shuffle(@word[1..$#word-1]), $word[-1];
}
```

**example output**

```
I have csrtuoetcnd a snrtig that ndees to be shlfeufd
```

Comment: That's good. But I don't want to split strings that has 4 characters or less. They are to be treated as words, so "IS" "A" "TO" "BE" never changes, and in "SHUFFLED" S & D don't changes places.

Comment: Okay, so what do you mean by *"`$string[0]` and `[-1]` remains untouched, other elements in between is supposed to be shuffled randomly"*. Do you want to shuffle all words in the sentence that are longer that four characters, while keeping the first and last letters of each word in place?

Answer (score -1):

If you want shuffle each word with four or more characters you can do it in this way.

- `my @ch = split //, shift` splits the argument of function taken by `shift` (it is shorthand for `shift(@_)`) by each char.
- `# /` is there just to fix wrong syntax highlighting.
- `join '', $ch[0], shuffle( @ch[ 1 .. $#ch - 1 ] ), $ch[-1]` shuffles and joins the string back together.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util qw(shuffle);

my $string = "I have constructed a string that needs to be shuffled";

sub shuffle_str {
    my @ch = split //, shift; # /
    join '', $ch[0], shuffle( @ch[ 1 .. $#ch - 1 ] ), $ch[-1];
}

my $shuffled = $string =~ s/(\w{4,})/shuffle_str($1)/ger;

print $shuffled, "\n";
```

And sample output

```
I have cutscntroed a sritng taht nedes to be sufehfld
```

Comment: Well, downvoting troll strikes again. BTW it works and do what described in question.

Comment: That's nice, but I really can't understand it :)

Comment: Care to elobarate exactly what it does?

Comment: I understand the regex, and that it replaces the $1 from the subroutine. but the my @ch = split //, shift; # /
    join '', $ch[0], shuffle( @ch[ 1 .. $#ch - 1 ] ), $ch[-1]; part is unclear to me

Comment: `my @ch = split //, shift;` splits argument of function taken by `shift` (it is shorthand for `shift(@_)`) by each char. `# /` is there just to fix wrong syntax highliting. `join '', $ch[0], shuffle( @ch[ 1 .. $#ch - 1 ] ), $ch[-1];` suffles and joins string back together.

Comment: It might be easier to explain in the body of the answer, comments with code in them aren't the easiest thing to read.

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil: You really aren't such a threat that people will downvote you out of jealousy. Please understand that it is simply because your Perl code is poor, and because your answers don't explain the solution. I anticipate another question about what is wrong with your code,  so I will say that it it the use of `# /` and the substitute modifiers `/e` and `/r` without explanation or comment. My own answer is nearly as bad, and that is because I think I am writing someone's homework, so I wanted to leave evidence that the OP hadn't done it himself.

Comment: I should also say that the manner of your posts is boastful rather than humbly helpful, and your code is complex and concise rather than clear and explicit. Even your belief that people are ganging up to vote against you is pompous